# Writing a Zsh function that auto reruns a command on file save

Tags: shell, zsh, inotify, inotify-tools

I want to write a Zsh function that looks like:

```
smartwatch [WATCH_FILE] [COMMAND_TO_RUN] [COMMAND_ARGS]
```

Such that after `WATCH_FILE` is saved, that `COMMAND_TO_RUN` will be run and `smartwatch` will wait for the file to be saved again. This would be helpful for me in this scenario:

```
smartwatch server.py python server.py
```

So everytime I modify the server file, the server gets restarted. I've heard that [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/#wiki-info) might be able to help, so I'm using `inotifywait`, but if someone knows a better tool, let me know. Here's what I have so far:

```
smartwatch() {                      
   WATCH=$1                         
   CMD=$2                           
   ARGS=$*[3,-1]                    
   $CMD $ARGS &!                    
   PID=$!                           
   inotifywait -qq $WATCH           
   kill $PID                        
   exec smartwatch $WATCH $CMD $ARGS
}
```

This solution is rather slow and not very elegant. Anyone know a way to make this more efficient or at least cleaner?

Comment: inotifywait will finish on the occurrence of any event.  You probably want to specify "-e modify -e move_self -e delete_self" to prevent restarting the daemon if any process reads the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some fiddling, here's what I ended up with:

```
onsave() {
   while true
   do
      eval "$1 &!"
      trap "kill $! &> /dev/null; return;" SIGINT SIGTERM
      inotifywait -e modify -qq $2
      kill $! &> /dev/null
   done
}
```

So you should be able to run `onsave "python server.py" server.py`